# XCTest() get parent of XCUIElement

Tags: swift, automation, automated-tests, xctest

This is the sample when i'm trying to print the element structure of an application when entering `po print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)` in terminal windows

```
tables, (address code like 0x00006b), traits: (some random number)
    cells, (address code), traits: (random number)
       others, (address code), traits: (random number), label: "Other Value"
       buttons, (address code), traits: (random number), identifier: "primaryButton", label: "Press ME"
```

so, basically, if i want to access `others` value, i just simple need access through its label:

`let cellsValue = XCUIApplication().tables.cells.otherElements.staticTexts["Other Value"];`

However, the problem is that `staticTexts` can be changed overtime, so my solution is that I can access to a element with specific identifier like:

```
let btnPrimary = XCUIApplication().tables.buttons["primaryBtn"];
```

and calling it's parent (cells element in this case) like:

```
let tableParent = btnPrimary.parent()
```

so that i can easily access to that element using this:

```
let otherElement = tableParent.otherElements.firstMatch.label
```

but the `parent()` function don't exist, so how can I get access to an element's parent?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem, i posted it here in case if anyone has the same problem like me. So, you don't have to find a parent based on their child which has unique identifier, you simply just need to find an element has that unique identifer basde on what XCTest() give. So basically, you have to do this:

```
let parent = XCUIApplication().tables.cell.containing(.button, "primaryButton")
```

and accessing their child by:

```
let otherValue = parent.otherElements.firstMatch()
```

which will return the first element has the type of `other` and if you want to access element index, calling `element(boundBy: )` method!

Comment: Your out of luck if the child doesn't have a unique id tho